# In Python How would you append values to numbers in list based on rules?

Tags: python, list, append

In Python, if I have a list of numbers ex. [14,6,8] how would I go about appending letters to each digit according to certain rules? Ex. if (n-2) /3=4 assign "b" and (n-2) /2= 2 assign "z"… therefore the string would be "14b,6z,8"

Comment: I'm not following your logic for why you're picking b or z; can you please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension and conditional expressions:

```
In [926]: l = [14, 6, 8]

In [927]: ['{}b'.format(n) if (n-2)/3==4 else '{}z'.format(n) if (n-2)/2==2 else str(n) for n in l]
Out[927]: ['14b', '6z', '8']
```

Here, we are iterating over the integers of the list, and setting the desired format using the conditional expressions based on conditions.

Prettified for reading:

```
['{}b'.format(num) if (num-2)/3==4 else \
 '{}z'.format(num) if (num-2)/2==2 else str(num) \
 for num in input_list]
```

Answer (score 3):

Define transformation function and use `map` for applying it on elements of list. Then construct result string:

```
a = [14, 6, 8]

def transform(x):
    if (x - 2) / 3 == 4:
        return f'{x}b'
    if (x - 2) / 2 == 2:
        return f'{x}z'
    return str(x)

print(','.join(map(transform, a)))
```

Output:

```
'14b,6z,8'
```

---

Or just using list comprehension:

```
','.join([f'{x}b' if (x - 2) / 3 == 4 else f'{x}z' if (x - 2) / 2 == 2 else str(x) 
          for x in a])
```